# How to combine date column and time column

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have data look like this

```
        Date        Time     Open     High      Low    Close  Volume
0      2013.07.09   7:00  101.056  101.151  101.016  101.130    1822
1      2013.07.09   8:00  101.130  101.257  101.128  101.226    2286
2      2013.07.09   9:00  101.226  101.299  101.175  101.180    2685
3      2013.07.09  10:00  101.178  101.188  101.019  101.154    2980
4      2013.07.09  11:00  101.153  101.239  101.146  101.188    2623
```

How to combine Date column and Time column into one column which is Date Time.
And I wonder if i do that whether I have to change the string to date. 
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have 'Date' column as timestamp then you convert them to a string and add them , then convert them into timestamp i.e

```
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].apply(str)+' '+df['Time'])
```

Output :

```
        Date   Time     Open     High      Low    Close  Volume  \
0 2013-07-09   7:00  101.056  101.151  101.016  101.130    1822   
1 2013-07-09   8:00  101.130  101.257  101.128  101.226    2286   
2 2013-07-09   9:00  101.226  101.299  101.175  101.180    2685   
3 2013-07-09  10:00  101.178  101.188  101.019  101.154    2980   
4 2013-07-09  11:00  101.153  101.239  101.146  101.188    2623   

             Datetime  
0 2013-07-09 07:00:00  
1 2013-07-09 08:00:00  
2 2013-07-09 09:00:00  
3 2013-07-09 10:00:00  
4 2013-07-09 11:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you so  much Bharath shetty. Could you tell me how to specify which data is string,date or time format?

Comment: You could use `print(df.dtypes)` to know what type each column is.

Comment: @ Bharath shetty How to replace this new column into Date and Time column in my dataframe?

Comment: Drop the columns after getting Datetime column i.e `df.drop(df[['Date','Time']], axis=1)`

Answer (score 1):

```
dataframe["Date Time"] = dataframe["Date"].map(str) + dataframe["Time"]
```

**Update**

Formatting the date you can use

```
dataframe["Date Time"] =pd.to_datetime(dataframe["Date"].map(str) +'-'+ dataframe["Time"])
```

and instead of replace you can delete those `Date` and `Time` column from the dataframe. like this

```
del dataframe["Date"], dataframe["Time"]
```

Comment: Thank R.A.Munna but I think that this is not the date format isn't it. How to change to be in datetime format. And I want this new column will be replace Date and Time column in my dataframe